# How Does Ctrl-K work in Stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, css, code-formatting

I am very curious to know how to implement the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (code sample) feature against code, 
For example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println.out("welcome");
}
```

That will be nicely formatted?

1. Do we require any package to implement this?
2. Any ready made code available to do this?

Can any one help me with this? I am planning to develop a site where this feature would be a real helpful.

Comment: Reopened - this is not a Meta question, it's a programming question using a feature on a familiar site as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [Google Javascript code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).

As [rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185541/rsp) mentioned in comments it works for [following list](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html) of languages.

Comment: @harigm, look at the test page: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html

Answer (score 0):

> Do we require any package to implement this?

You need some software.

> Any ready made code avaialble to do this?

SO uses markdown. There are implementations for most popular languages.